# Regex match except urls starting with a custome strings

Tags: regex, url, match, except

I have a text and a regex pattern

text is something like

```
foo https://www.google.hu <img ... src="http://a-page.com/foobar.jpg" ...> bar
```

the regex

```
/(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+)\.([a-z]{1,5}+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\=\&\-\_\~\/\%\+\;]+)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+))?/i
```

and i'd update it with a special case

if url starting with src=" it would be great if regex matches dont contains the image url only other urls

i tried this

```
/(?!src\=\")(http|https|ftp)\:\/\/(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+)\.([a-z]{1,5}+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\?\=\&\-\_\~\/\%\+\;]+)?(\#([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+))?/
```

but it doesnt work

Could you help me, please?

I know I could add (^|\s) to pattern, but it won't work in case when I want to hide urls cause user can write any char before url and the url is no longer hidden and some other regex codes are in source too and one of them is a img bb tag code, and I dont want to hide (replace) it's url

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Why are you escaping all these char? Regex will be clearer if you're escaping only those that are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I had difficulties to understand what exactly you want, but I guess you mean that you have a text with various URLs inside and you don't want to match those which are included in a html `img` tag. If so, try this:

```
/(?<!src\=\")(https?|ftp):\/\/(www\.)?([\w\-\.]+)\.([a-z]{1,5}+)\/?([\w\.\?\=\&\-\~\/\%\+\;]+)?(\#(\w+))?/
```

Notes:

- You can replace `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with character class `\w` (read more in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)).
- The `(?!pattern)` assertion you tried is a negative *look-ahead* assertion. In your case you want a negative *look-behind* `(?<!pattern)` (again you can read [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more info).

Comment: +1 didn't try your answer (I believe it works) but the link to perlre and your observation about look-behind were helpful to me. Thx.